# string xtic labels with yerrorbars and separate title for each row

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file, `file.dat`,  that contains string and numeric `xticlabels`

```
STD 0.34 0.04
0.1 0.4  0.03
0.2 0.3  0.04
0.3 0.31 0.045
```

Column No.1 is for `xticlabels`, Column 2 is for value to plot against `xlabels` and Column 3 if for `yerror` bars.

I want to plot this file with `yerrorbars`, labels and separate title and colour for each row, but problem is that with `yerrorbars`, `xtics` are problematic and without `yerrorbars`, `xtics` are displayed correctly.

I tried without `yerrorbars` and it gave correct result

```
plot "file.dat" u 2:xticlabels(1)
```

[image: correct plot without yerrorbars]

However, when i tried to plot `yerrorbars` also it gave incorrect `xlabels`. I have used this command

```
plot "file.dat" u 2:xticlabels(1):3 w yerrorbars
```

Now I get this result with incorrect x labels and column 3 values are shown in `xticlabels`

[image: wrong xlabels]

Can anyone tell me how can I get it correct with `yerrorbars` with separate title and color for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this, instead of your plot command.

```
set xrange [-1:4]
plot "file.dat" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars
```

The special column number `0` in `using` spec means the sequential order of each point within a data set which start from 0. For detail, see `help pseudocolumns`. By using this, you have explicitly given an integer value for x that is incremented by one.

And, note that `xticslabels` is appended to the end of the using spec.